# Can't query JavaScript REST API

Tags: rest, api, powershell, scripting

I'm writing PowerShell script for listing all information from page https://testpage.com/api/usergroups.

How can get the output?

For this I used next code

```bsh
function Get-Data([string]$username, [string]$password, [string]$url) {
    # Step 1. Create a username:password pair
    $credPair = "$($username):$($password)"

    # Step 2. Encode the pair to Base64 string
    $encodedCredentials =[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($credPair))

    # Step 3. Form the header and add the Authorization attribute to it
    $headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic $encodedCredentials" }

    # Step 4. Make the GET request
    $responseData = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing

    return $responseData
}
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

Get-Data -username user -password pass -url https://testpage.com/api/usergroups
```

As the result I got next error

```html
<noscript>
    <p>
        <strong>Note:</strong> Since your browser does not support JavaScript,
        you must press the Continue button once to proceed.
    </p>
</noscript>
```

Comment: We can't tell you how to use an API that we know nothing about. Please check the API documentation of whoever is providing that API.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers this is synopsys product and I can't find how to work with their API. I found just requests, but got error

Comment: It is supposed to be accessed via Browser, since you are asked for JavaScript. Otherwise you could possibly use a headless browser like Phantomjs.